# GCM Token returned by InstanceID API gives NotRegistered error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, instanceid

I'm using GCM in my app and using the `InstanceId` API to generate GCM tokens. I'm facing this issue where the token returned by the `InstanceId` API is invalid.

I use Postman to check the token and every now and then in some device, trying to use the token throws a NotRegistered error. Although, if I then forcefully execute the `GCMInstanceIdListener` service, it calls the `GCMRegistrationService` again and this time I get the correct token.

Is there a way to check if the token I receive in the `GCMRegistrationService` works? I know we can make a call to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` and verify the token but it requires the server key to be passed in the header and I don't want to store it on the client.

This is how my code looks like :

```
public class GCMInstanceIdListener extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMRegistrationService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}


public class GCMRegistrationService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "GCMRegistrationService";

    public GCMRegistrationService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(BuildConfig.GCM_SENDER_ID,
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        Log.d(TAG, "GCM Token : " + token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your `GCMRegistrationService` every time your app fires up, and check to see if the token you have saved locally on the client matches the one received.

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String token = InstanceID.getInstance(this).getToken(BuildConfig.GCM_SENDER_ID,
            GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String savedToken = prefs.getString("token", "");

    if(!token.equals(savedToken)) {
        prefs.edit().putString("token", token).apply();
        sendTokenToBackend(token);    // If needed
    }
}
```

**EDIT :** Also, make sure you have the GET_ACCOUNTS permission. Recently, I removed this permission from my app and I got NotRegistered error on my devices. If your app targets API 23+, you need to request this permission at runtime.

Comment: I could do that but in our use case, we need to send a push message to the user as soon as they open the app for the first time. Running `GCMRegistrationService` would help only from the second time onwards. Even on a clean install, when `GCMRegistrationService` is called for the first time, I get an invalid token.

Comment: Why don't you follow Google's example gcm client. It uses a local broadcast to notify the activity that registration is complete. You can then proceed with the rest of your logic. As for an invalid token, the only 2 things I can think of is that either your google-services.json is at fault (corrupted file, maybe) or you do not have the GET_ACCOUNTS permission (Android 6.0+ permissions issue, maybe)

Comment: Hmm I'll check that. Although we do have the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission in our manifest, and I've re-copied the json file a couple of times, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: GET_ACCOUNTS is defined as a "normal" permission, but it apparently needs to be requested during runtime on API 23+, as if it was a "dangerous" permission. At least this is what happens in my app.

Comment: Yup, but we're not currently targeting API 23+ in our app.